# Subgroups of Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{12})/\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, extension-field, roots-of-unity

We have $\xi_{12}$ denotes the 12-th root of unity. I'm having trouble getting the idea of how to find these subgroups. I know there has to be 4 since irr($\xi_{12}, \mathbb{Q}) = \Phi_{12}(X)$ which has degree 4. I also know that one of the elements has to be complex conjugation, one the identity map. When i have the third one, the 4th one has to be the combination of that one and complex conjugation, but how do i find the third one? I know Gal($\mathbb{Q}(\xi_{12})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, can that maybe help me?

Comment: The isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^\times \overset{\sim}{\to} \operatorname{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\mathbb{Q})$ is given by $k \mapsto \sigma_k$ where $\sigma_k: \zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^k$. So all the automorphisms are given by raising $\xi_{12}$ to some power. Does that help?

Comment: That does help! Thank you very much!

Comment: The degree of $\Phi_{12}$ doesn't tell the number of subgroups. How many cyclic subgroups does $\Bbb{Z_2\times Z_2}$ have ? How many non-cyclic ones ?